# FXMLLoader.load() throws IllegalAccessError

Tags: java, javafx, openjfx

I am building *javafx* application in which i am trying to load .fxml file using `FXMLLoader`. Doing so, it throws `IllegalAccessError` Without `FXMLLoader` application runs fine. I am using *Maven* tool and dependencies are included:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>15.0.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
    <version>15.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Overriden start method:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
{
    System.out.println(getClass().getResource(""));
    URL url = getClass().getResource("fxml/defaultScene.fxml");
    Scene scene = new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(url)); // <- exception occurs here
    ViewController viewController = new ViewController(scene);
```

module-info.java:

```
module DesktopApp
{
    exports core;
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires javafx.fxml;
}
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class com.sun.javafx.scene.control.ControlHelpe
r (in unnamed module @0x67583cb) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.scene.layout.RegionHelper (in module javafx.graphics
) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.scene.layout to unnamed module @0x67583cb
```

Comment: module-info looks incomplete - missing `requires javafx.controls`

Comment: @kleopatra This actually solved my issue. If you want, you can post answer and i will accept it. Thank you for help.

Comment: I'm surprised your code managed to compile. Did you compile your code as a module?

Comment: @Slaw good point :) The maven deps seem okay, though not matching the module-info - strange that such mismatch doesn't boil up at compile time

Comment: @Slaw well... i did maven update, then maven clean verify in Eclipse IDE. Then just tried to run with run as java application.

Comment: I wonder, do you only reference classes from the `javafx.controls` module in the FXML file?

Comment: @Slaw yeah, they are referenced there. Guess that was Scene Builder job.

Comment: I'm wondering if they are _only_ referenced there. As in you don't reference any classes from the `javafx.controls` module in actual source code (i.e. `.java` files). If so, it's possible this is a weird corner case. A combination of needing the controls module at run-time, not referencing any controls in code so you don't "need" it at compile-time, and probably a mixture of `--class-path` and `--module-path` configuration (performed by Maven).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is adding `requires javafx.controls` to `module-info.java`. It was compile-able, because there are no referenced classes from javafx.controls package in .java file and exception was raised because classes from javafx.controls are referenced in fxml file.